# How to check if var1 is neither var2 or var3 in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that sets var1=value1 and so on, the file looks like this:

```
SET var1=value1
SET var2=value2
SET var3=value3
```

I need to check if var1 is NOT the same as var2 or var3, if it isn't the same to none of var1 or var2 then `ECHO something`

I am asking this because

```
IF NOT "var1"=="var2","var3" (
     echo something
)
```

This does not work so i am wondering how i can fix it

Comment: Just to be sure : you mean "if it isn't similar to none of **var2 or var3** then ...", right ?

Comment: Similar and same are completely different things; as far as I'm concerned the string, `value1` is similar to `value3` but it is not the same! As a recommendation when you `Set` a variable, you should use this syntax, `Set "var1=value1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF NOT "var1"=="var2" (
    IF NOT "var1"=="var3" (
        echo var1 is neither 2 nor 3
    )
)
```

First check that var1 is not var2, and then check that it is also not var3. (you can exchange var2 and var3, if you want).

Also, remember that you can use `IF /I NOT ...` instead, if you want to do a case-insensitive check (uppercase and lowercase characters treated as the same)

Comment: Thank you this code works perfectly now i just need to adjust it to my preferences, thanks a lot

Comment: That code is incorrect, but I've fixed it to make it so! It does however not make a case insensitive comparison, which should be in the format, `IF /I NOT…`. This means that currently, although 'similar', `"value1"` is not the same as `"Value1"`.

Comment: @Compo thank you for the missing parenthesis, wrote that in a bit of a hurry. I'll add your comment about case insensitive search too in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your values in an array and every time a new value comes in check whether this value is already part of the array:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]==value){
       //value is already set
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Batch does not have the concept of array. And many other languages, such as brainfuck and Hexagony and ///.

Comment: I know, simulating array with variable names is possible, but implementing array in Batch when you don't need them is never a good idea. Also on SO we need code, not pseudocode - if you want pseudocode go to https://cs.stackexchange.com.